# При использовании аннотации Transactional вылазит ошибка

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, crud

Суть проблемы: мне надо, чтобы изменения в бд откатывались после тестов, для этого я через аннотацию `@Transactional` пометил тестовый класс, но при запуске вылетает ошибка.
PS: пытался также создавать бин transactionManager через xml, ошибка также вылетала.
pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>news-portal</name>
  <groupId>ru.vegadev</groupId>
  <artifactId>news-portal</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <version>42.2.8</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.zaxxer/HikariCP -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
      <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
      <version>3.4.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

      <!--<dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
      </dependency>-->

    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
      <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-test -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-tx -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
          <version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-all -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
      <version>1.10.19</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.dbunit/dbunit -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
          <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.1</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
      <version>1.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
      <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
      <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.springtestdbunit</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-test-dbunit</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>*</groupId>
          <artifactId>*</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
  </build>
</project>
```

UserDAOImplTest

```
    package ru.vegd.dao.impl;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import ru.vegd.dao.UserDAO;
import ru.vegd.entity.User;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("/springTest.xml")
@Transactional
public class UserDAOImplTest{

    @Autowired
    UserDAO userDAO;

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    User user;

    @Before
    public void before() {
        user = new User();
    }

    @Test
    public void getAll() throws Exception {

        List<User> persons = userDAO.getAll();

        Connection con = dataSource.getConnection();

    }

    @Test
    public void add() throws SQLException {

    }

    @Test
    public void read() {



    }

    @Test
    public void delete() throws SQLException {

    }

    @Test
    public void update() {
    }
}
```

springTest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="ru.vegd/" />

</beans>
```

SpringConfig

```
package ru.vegd.config;

import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig;
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@PropertySource("database.properties")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class SpringConfig {

    @Value("${db.url}")
    private String dbUrl;
    @Value("${db.username}")
    private String dbUsername;
    @Value("${db.password}")
    private String dbPassword;
    @Value("${db.driver}")
    private String dbDriver;
    @Value("${db.schema}")
    private String dbSchema;
    @Value("${db.testschema}")
    private String dbTestSchema;

    private int DB_POOL_MAX_SIZE = 5;

    /*@Bean
    public DataSource dataSource () {
        HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
        hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl(dbUrl);
        hikariConfig.setUsername(dbUsername);
        hikariConfig.setPassword(dbPassword);
        hikariConfig.setDriverClassName(dbDriver);
        hikariConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(DB_POOL_MAX_SIZE);
        hikariConfig.setSchema(dbSchema);

        HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);

        return dataSource;
    }*/

    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource dataSourceTest()
    {
        HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
        hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl(dbUrl);
        hikariConfig.setUsername(dbUsername);
        hikariConfig.setPassword(dbPassword);
        hikariConfig.setDriverClassName(dbDriver);
        hikariConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(DB_POOL_MAX_SIZE);
        hikariConfig.setSchema(dbTestSchema);

        HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);

        return dataSource;
    }

}
```

Application

```
package ru.vegd;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import java.sql.SQLException;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    private final static org.apache.log4j.Logger logger = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Application.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

[image: Структура проекта]

Ошибки

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager' available
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:351)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:342)
        at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TestContextTransactionUtils.retrieveTransactionManager(TestContextTransactionUtils.java:195)
        at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener.getTransactionManager(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:364)
        at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener.getTransactionManager(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:345)
        at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:198)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:289)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
        at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    17:14:07.196 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TestContextTransactionUtils - Caught exception while retrieving PlatformTransactionManager for test context [DefaultTestContext@6cc7b4de testClass = UserDAOImplTest, testInstance = ru.vegd.dao.impl.UserDAOImplTest@5606c0b, testMethod = delete@UserDAOImplTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@32cf48b7 testClass = UserDAOImplTest, locations = '{classpath:/springTest.xml}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@29b5cd00, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@45820e51, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@7a30d1e6], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map[[empty]]]
    org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'transactionManager' available
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:805)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1278)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:297)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207)
        at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TestContextTransactionUtils.retrieveTransactionManager(TestContextTransactionUtils.java:219)
        at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener.getTransactionManager(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:364)
        at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener.getTransactionManager(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:345)
        at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:198)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:289)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
        at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    17:14:07.199 [main] WARN org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while invoking 'beforeTestMethod' callback on TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@2698dc7] for test method [public void ru.vegd.dao.impl.UserDAOImplTest.delete() throws java.sql.SQLException] and test instance [ru.vegd.dao.impl.UserDAOImplTest@5606c0b]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to retrieve PlatformTransactionManager for @Transactional test: [DefaultTestContext@6cc7b4de testClass = UserDAOImplTest, testInstance = ru.vegd.dao.impl.UserDAOImplTest@5606c0b, testMethod = delete@UserDAOImplTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@32cf48b7 testClass = UserDAOImplTest, locations = '{classpath:/springTest.xml}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@29b5cd00, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@45820e51, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@7a30d1e6], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map[[empty]]]
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:94)
        at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:199)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:289)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
        at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to retrieve PlatformTransactionManager for @Transactional test: [DefaultTestContext@6cc7b4de testClass = UserDAOImplTest, testInstance = ru.vegd.dao.impl.UserDAOImplTest@5606c0b, testMethod = delete@UserDAOImplTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@32cf48b7 testClass = UserDAOImplTest, locations = '{classpath:/springTest.xml}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@29b5cd00, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@45820e51, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@7a30d1e6], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map[[empty]]]

    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:94)
    at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:199)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У тебя жуткий микс Spring и SpringBoot, стоит определиться, чего ты хочешь :)

Если SpringBoot

1. Убери `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) @ContextConfiguration("/springTest.xml")` и поставь `@SpringBootTest`
2. Перенеси `@EnableTransactionManagement` в `Application`
3. Переименуй `database.properties` в `application.properties` и переименуй свойства, чтобы они соответствовали СпрингБутовским автосвойствам, см. `spring.datasource.*` https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#data-properties
4. Удали springTest.xml
5. Удали SpringConfig

По идее, тут уже должно заработать.